# Make virtual joystick preserve aspect ratio Android in Unity

Tags: unity, android, gui, scale, aspect-ratio

When I start my game on Android my virtual joysticks stops being round.

Here you can see it:

[image]

Here is the project on PC at the same time:

[image]

Here are my UI settings for the Joystick:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please, help me to find a way to preserve the roundness on the Android phone. It feels to me that the solution to the problem is straightforward, but my lack of knowledge prevent me from getting it. What I tried to do is to tweak settings in Editor, in particular I checked preserve ratio on all elements images as you can see on screenshots, but it did not help. I think it did not due to the fact that there is a code executed every time which is this:

```
Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.LandscapeLeft;
```

And I think that it changes ratio even though I preserved it in Editor. So, help me out of the problem, please.

Comment: Why is `Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.LandscapeLeft;` executed every time? If you don't know if it's causing the bug, disable it and check if it solves the problem.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with your joystick. *EVERYTHING* in your scene is getting squashed. https://s12.postimg.org/sofff4ycd/squash.png

Comment: https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/android-changing-screen-orientation-stretches-view-after-using-setresolution

Comment: @Spectre, I do not understand the solution provided by you. Sorry.

Comment: Why do you use the Screen.orientation?

Comment: @Spectre, I would like my game to be horizontally displayed. So that the game was going from top of the phone to the bottom instead of from right to left. And as far as I know there is no other way to achieve it except Screen.orientation. Am I right?

Comment: Check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to specify game orientation, go to `File -> Build Settings -> Player Settings` and there open a tab `Resolution and Presentation`.

Set your desired orientation there:

[image]

And delete that line: `ScreenOrientation.something` from your code. I'm 99% sure that it causes all the stretching.

Comment: Thanks for the attention. Hope it will help. I have no opportunity to check it right now, but I will do it tomorrow.

Comment: If it does not, feel free to write here, I'll try to help :)

ps. but it will work ;v

Comment: Your solution does not work as I want. It has the same effect as before. Everything is squeezed just the same way.

Comment: Export your project and upload it somewhere so I can download it. 
Go to `Assets -> Export Package` and upload the .unityPackage to some dropbox so I can download it.

Comment: Wait a moment. I will be right back.

Comment: It is my first time exporting of a project in Unity. Here it is : http://www.filedropper.com/showdownload.php/squezzedproblem. Did I make it right?

Comment: Nope, it's some error website ;( Try: https://uploadfiles.io/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60695/discussion-between-yaroslav-and-spectre).